# Retornar ultima entrada de cada objeto no banco de dados

Tags: sql, query, postgresql

Eu tenho duas tabelas:

```
               monitor_carro
id serial | setor_id |  modelo | ano | placa


               monitor_evento
id serial | lat | long | data | fkfuncionario_id | time | carro
```

A tabela monitor_evento só tem uma chave estrangeira que é funcionario e em ambas as tabelas a chave primaria é a *id serial*.

Supondo que eu tenha diversos carros inseridos na tabela monitor_carro e que tenha diversas entradas desses carros no meu bd. Gostaria de uma ajuda para retornar a ultima entrada de cada carro na tabela monitor_evento.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Quer retornar o último registro selecionado?

Comment: Estou trabalhando com o google maps. As entradas dos carros nada mais são do que marcadores que eu ponho no mapa através de um JSON usando a latitude e a longitude deles, mas na hora de filtra-los eu não estou conseguindo pegar a ultima posição de cara carro no banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct on (carro) *
from monitor_evento
order by carro, id_serial desc
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo, não imaginei o mais simples. Muito obrigado!!